# Why do I not get the same coefficients as linear regression when my elastic net regression model has alpha = 0 & l1_ratio =0

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I am using the `sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNet` model and I am trying to re-create linear regression by setting `alph = 0` and `l1_ratio = 0` but I am getting very different coefficients. Does anyone know why? I thought using those parameters should get me the regular linear regression coefficients.

My code is below and attached is the image of the output.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import ElasticNet
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

linear_model = LinearRegression().fit(xtrain, ytrain)
linear_coeffs = linear_model.coef_

enet_model = ElasticNet(alpha = 0, l1_ratio=0).fit(xtrain,ytrain)
enet_coef = enet_model.coef_

linear_model = LinearRegression().fit(xtrain, ytrain)
linear_coef = linear_model.coef_

sum_squares_coeff_diff = (np.square(enet_coef))/(np.square(linear_coef))

for i in range(len(enet_coef)):
    print("enet_coef, linear_coef, ratio:           %f           %f           %f" %(enet_coef[i],linear_coef[i],sum_squares_coeff_diff[i]))

print('ratio enet_reg sum squares coef / linear reg sum squares coef:   %f' %(np.sum(np.square(enet_coef))/np.sum(np.square(linear_coef))))

(len(enet_coef),len(linear_coef)))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sawLq.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO; please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

When I reproduce this code (in Google Colab), I get the following warning.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:9: UserWarning: With alpha=0, this algorithm does not converge well. You are advised to use the LinearRegression estimator
```

The documentation (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf3/sklearn/linear_model/_coordinate_descent.py#L557) says

```
Currently, l1_ratio <= 0.01 is not reliable,
    unless you supply your own sequence of alpha.
```

UPD: the underlying optimization algorithm is coordinate descent. The L1 penalization makes it sensitive to the sign of each entry. I guess that's the reason for not proper convergence.

Comment: Thanks for the answer kate-melnykova. I tried the same thing in Google Colab and got the warning message as well. Do you know if a very small alpha would encounter the same problem? I was getting sum(squared(enet_coef)) > sum(squared(linear_coef)) when I applied alpha = .0001 and l1_ratio = .9 and similar values. This was counter to my intuition because I thought any alpha and any l1_ratio should always add some shrinkage not add.

Comment: Hmm... I don't know the smallest acceptable values for the minimization problem.

`sum(squared(enet_coef)) > sum(squared(linear_coef))` is actually correct. Note that the linear regression finds the minimum 2-norm solution of the equation (assuming that there is no noise). The L1 penalization makes the L1 norm (sum of abs values) to be smaller, which, in turn, promotes sparsity of the reconstructed vector.

Comment: In other words,  in the undersampled noiseless case, the linear regression will generally return the minimum 2-norm solution -- and then the obtained inequality makes sense. The L1 regularization makes L1 norm small and is used to find a solution whose majority of entries are zeros, and whose L1.